# Should i save my User Details in Viewmodel as well as SharedPrefernces?

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-viewmodel

Should i update my User Details in `Viewmodel` as well as `SharedPrefernces`?

For example, i have fields like

```
name
age
currentSalary
organisation
+8 more
```

I have few doubts now:

- Am i supposed to create LiveData of each of these fields?
- Also, i have to save them in `Sharedprefernces` too. So doesn't this feel redundant? First, saving it in Viewmodel and then saving it in `Sharedprefernces`.
- When i move from screen 1 to screen 2, should i fetch user's name from `ViewModel` or the `api`?

**MainViewModel.kt Sample Code**

```
private val _experience = MutableLiveData<String>()
val experience : LiveData<String>
    get() = _experience

private val _name = MutableLiveData<String>()
val name : LiveData<String>
    get() = _name

private val _isLoggedIn = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
val isLoggedIn : LiveData<Boolean>
    get() = _isLoggedIn

fun setName(name: String){
    _name.value = name
}

fun setExperience(exp: String){
    _experience.value = exp
}

fun logIn(){
    _isLoggedIn.value = true
}
```

**MyFragment**

```js
binding.btnSubmit.setOnClickListener {
  val name = binding.etName.text.toString()
  val email = binding.etEmail.text.toString()
  val age = binding.etAge.text.toString()
  val org = binding.etOrg.text.toString()
//saving in viewmodel
  mainViewModel.setName(name)
  mainViewModel.setCurrentOrganisation(org)
  mainViewModel.setEmail(email)
  mainViewModel.setAge(Integer.valueOf(age))
//saving in sharedpreference
  editor.putInt("age", Integer.valueOf(age))
  editor.putString("name", name)
  editor.putString("email", email)
  editor.putString("org", org)
}
```

To me, `My fragment` looks a lot of lines of codes. I don't know if i am using the right approach.

Comment: You should make a UserData data class that has each of these properties in it. Then you only need one LiveData and one setter function in your ViewModel. I wouldn’t touch SharedPreferences in your Fragment if it’s the same data that’s in your LiveData. The Fragment can be responsible for backing up to and restoring from SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 3):

The `ViewModel` is meant to sit between your *View* layer (the UI) and the *Data* layer (the core app functionality, stored data etc). A *ViewModel* acts as a go-between, passing data to the UI for display, and translating UI events to function calls in the app.

The `ViewModel`'s state is transient - in Android it sticks around long enough to survive things like `Activity` recreation. If you use the `SavedStateHandle` component, you can store its running state so it can be rebuilt if the app is destroyed in the background - but this explicitly won't survive the app being closed and restarted. The *ViewModel* isn't about *persisting data*, just about the current, temporary state of things.

So actually *storing* your data is part of the *data layer*. That's where the `SharedPreferences` comes in - but you could be storing (and reading) data using all kinds of storage, even across a network. The *ViewModel's* role is to access that data, and expose it to the UI somehow - possibly even transforming that data into a more suitable form for the UI to consume.

So while you might have duplication going on, there's a reason for it. `SharedPreferences` is there to actually *store* and *persist* the data. `LiveData` is just there for the *UI* to see what it should be displaying. They may or may not be the same thing!

---

Have a look at this Android guide on [designing your app architecture](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture) - it goes into the theory behind how you organise things, and how the data flow works. You don't necessarily need to follow all of it, but the broad strokes are good to know - that way if you want to deviate from that for simplicity in a particular situation, you'll know why you're doing it and what compromises you're making (and whether they matter in this case).

For your data update... there's two ways you can go about it. One is to make the *ViewModel* (gonna say VM for brevity) update the data layer, and then have the data layer push *new* data to the VM, which the VM displays in its `LiveData`. This is the kind of thing you do when you're using [observable queries](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/async-queries) with a database, where updates to a table push new data to the observer.

All the VM has to worry about is pushing data to the data layer (e.g. calling a *delete item* function). When the data changes, it's pushed to the observing VM, which just displays the data as usual (e.g. setting it on a `LiveData`), which causes the UI to get an update and display the new state... So instead of the VM getting the delete event, and having to worry about updating its own internal state, it just passes the delete request to the data layer. Then the new state arrives later, and the VM just uses that - a new list, whatever. The data layer *tells the view model what to display*, in the same way the VM tells the *UI* what to display.

(It might not be worth the effort writing a thing that updates the `SharedPreferences` and then tells the VM to display that data, so you *could* just do all this in the VM as a kind of combination of VM and data layer - but it helps to know why you're doing it, what it's a shortcut *for*, y'know?)

---

As for the "lots of `LiveData` objects" bit, [have a look at this section on UI State](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer/stateholders). Basically, the officially recommended approach is that the the UI's state *as a whole* is pushed by the VM. So instead of separate `LiveData` objects for each property (name, age etc) you'd have a *single object* that contains that data, and a `LiveData` that pushes *that*. Whenever something about that data changes, you push a new instance of that data object. (*Data classes* can help here, with their `copy` functions that let you change specific values and keep the rest)

So your UI just observes that one state `LiveData`, and wires it up to the UI components - your `TextView`s, `CheckBox`es etc. The approach they're talking about isn't just data - it's also UI state, which may not be what you're storing in your actual data layer (e.g. if a particular section is expanded, or if some list items are checked for a potential delete operation). Exactly how much you want to encapsulate in one object is up to you - but pushing your actual data in a single data structure isn't a bad idea!

Sorry that was a bit long, but hopefully it helps a bit